# How to fix xml tags in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have empty tag in oracle sql like

```
    <ID></ID>
```

I need to change it to

```
    <ID/>
```

in oracle sql.
Anyone have the solution for it?

```
Expected:"<ID/>"
Actual:"<ID></ID>"
```

I am using this Oracle XML query to generate the XML:

```
Select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT XMLELEMENT("EMP",XMLATTRIBUTES('NIKHIL' "NAME" )
       ,XMLELEMENT("ID",ID)
      ,XMLELEMENT("DESIGNATION",DESIGNATION)) ) as "XML" 
from (select '1' "ID",'DEVELOPER' "DESIGNATION" 
      from dual 
      union 
      select null "ID",'DEVELOPER' "DESIGNATION" from dual )
```

Comment: These tags are literally the same. Why do you like to change it?

Comment: In kettle old version i was getting <ID/> when i am running through kettle new version  I am getting <ID></ID>..output should be same as old

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include clarifications or additional information. Code is especially hard to read as a comment, due to poor formatting and non-existent layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap it in a xmlroot element, you get the tag  as desired.

```
  Select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT 
      XMLROOT(
      XMLELEMENT
      (
          "EMP",XMLATTRIBUTES('NIKHIL' "NAME" )
          ,XMLELEMENT("ID",ID)
          ,XMLELEMENT("DESIGNATION",DESIGNATION) 
      ), version '1.0" encoding="Windows-1250')) as "XML" 
  from (select '1' "ID",'DEVELOPER' "DESIGNATION" 
        from dual 
        union 
        select null "ID",'DEVELOPER' "DESIGNATION" from dual )
```

Result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<EMP NAME="NIKHIL">
<ID/>
<DESIGNATION>DEVELOPER</DESIGNATION>
</EMP>
```